# near "Column": syntax error. problem when rename or drop column in sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

tables

```
db.("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS ayet ( id INTEGER, User_Name INTEGER DEFAULT(0),PRIMARY KEY(id AUTOINCREMENT))");

db.("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS sure ( id INTEGER, User_Name INTEGER DEFAULT(0),PRIMARY KEY(id AUTOINCREMENT))");
```

when i rename or delete column

```
await db.execute("ALTER TABLE ayet RENAME COLUMN User_Name TO New_Name");
await db.execute("ALTER TABLE ayet DELETE COLUMN User_Name");
```

or

```
await db.execute("ALTER TABLE ayet RENAME 'User_Name' TO 'New_Name'");
await db.execute("ALTER TABLE ayet DELETE COLUMN 'User_Name'");
```

i take this problem

```
near "COLUMN": syntax error
I/flutter (22068): DatabaseException(near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , 
while compiling: ALTER TABLE ayet RENAME COLUMN User_Name TO New_Name) sql 'ALTER TABLE 
ayet RENAME COLUMN User_Name TO New_Name' args []
```

Comment: await db.execute("ALTER TABLE ayet RENAME User_Name TO New_Name");